# Program to shift elements in an array (Not getting correct output)

Tags: c

I am trying to make a c program for the following question:

> Given a set of elements stored in an array and a number 'm', design an Algorithm and write the subsequent C program to perform cyclic right shift of the array by 'm' places. For example, if the elements are 12, 13, 16, 7, 10 and m =2 then the resultant set will be 7, 10, 12, 13, 16.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> Number of elements in the set: 'n'
>   element-1
>   element-2
>   ...
>   element-n
>   value of 'm'
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Elements in the set after right shift by 'm' places

The program which I have written is as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
 int n,i,j,m,temp1,temp2;

printf("Given n:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

int array[n];

printf("Enter the elements\n");

for (i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

printf("Enter the shifts needed\n");
scanf("%d", &m);

for(i = 0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        temp1 = array[j+1];
        array[j+1] = array[j];
        temp2 = array[j+2];
        array[j+2] = temp1;
        temp1 = array[j+3];
        array[j+3] = temp2;
        array[j] = temp1;
    }
}

for (i = 0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%d\t", array[i]);
}
}
```

The output is the same set of numbers as the input.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you haven't used a debugger before, now is the perfect time to learn how to use one. With a debugger you can step though your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. A debugger is a crucial tool for any C programmer, and knowing how to use one is a crucial skill.

Comment: this is not the place for code dumping and help you, we're not remote programmers. Please, read the [FAQ]. Show us a [MCVE]. What have you tried? Did you even debug this code?

Comment: I think there is some problem with the for(j=0...) loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , you can create a new array to put the numbers shifted so you dont get confused with the temps and simplify your code:

```
int new_array[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  new_array[(i+m)%n]=array[i];
}
```